# Matrix characteristic polynomial: is there a fast way to verify?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, characteristic-polynomial

I am asking this question in the context of the following question:

[Need help to understand a solution to a polynomial problem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3785344/need-help-to-understand-a-solution-to-a-polynomial-problem#3785344)

In the above question, it was stated that the characteristic polynomial is

$$\lambda^2-(a^3+d^3+3abdc+3bcd)\lambda+(ad-bc)^3=0$$

for the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}^3$$

**Since assumingly it is given by the solution of a textbook, the calculation should be somehow reasonable.**

When I multiply out the matrix three times I get

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a^3+2abc+bcd & a^2b+b^2c+abd+bd^2 \\ a^2c+acd+bc^2+cd^2 & abc+2bcd+d^3 \end{pmatrix}$$

I can see how the $\lambda$ term has coefficient $a^3+d^3+3abc+3bcd$ even though the calculation is not so easy, but it really seems impossible to do the $(ad-bc)^3$ part by hand.

There must be something missing instead of doing the $4$-term by $4$-term multiplication by hand.

Comment: If $A$ denotes the matrix, the $\det(A^3) = \det(A)^3$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I understood now.