# Why are the eigenvalues of $A^k$ precisely the $k$-th powers of eigenvalues of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

It's clear that $k$-th powers of EV of $A$ are all EV of $A^k$, but the reverse inclusion isn't obvious to me.

For reference, this question has been posted before ([Eigenvalues and power of a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241764/eigenvalues-and-power-of-a-matrix)), but I couldn't find an actually valid proof for the general case in that thread. For $\Bbb C$ there's a theorem that states for $f$ analytic that $f(\text{Spec}(A))=\text{Spec}(f(A))$, but this doesn't work for an arbitrary field $\Bbb K$.

Comment: I think the argument based on Jordan form in that post works for any algebraically closed field.

Comment: This can be false for non-algebraically-closed fields.  You can pass to an algebraic closure and make the argument work.

Comment: Assuming that the field is algebraically closed, triangularise $A$ and the rest is straightforward.

Comment: It's not true for an arbitrary field. Not even for $\Bbb R$: Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$, $k=2$. $A^2=-I$ but $A$ has no eigenvalues...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not true for an arbitrary field. Let $\Bbb K=\Bbb R$, $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$, $k=2$; then $A^k=-I$ but $A$ has no eigenvalues.

A simple self-contained proof for an algebraically closed field: Say $a$ is an eigenvalue of $A^k$. There exist $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k\in\Bbb K$ with $$z^k-a=\prod_{j=1}^k(z-\lambda_j).$$Hence $$A^k-aI=\prod_{j=1}^k(A-\lambda_jI).$$Since $A^k-aI$ is singular this shows that at least one of the $A-\lambda_jI$ must be singular. (Note that $\lambda_j^k=a$, so this shows that $a$ is the $k$-th power of an eigenvalue of $A$.)

Comment: I completely forgot to consider the case of when the matrix has no EV in the ground field, thanks. Also, I think you forgot to include the power in "say $a$ is an EV of $A$" (you meant to say $A^k$, no?).

Comment: @V.Ch. yes of course that was supposed to be $A^k$, thanks.